# gracefully clean up bound service when activity is getting swiped from the recents

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I have a bound service which goes to the foreground when needed.
Here's a simplified version of what I have:

```
class MyService extends Service {
    private static final ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder serviceBinder) {
            instance.bound();
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            instance.unbound();
        }
    };
    private static MyService instance;

    public MyService() {
        instance = this;
    }

    public static boolean bind(final Context context) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        return context.bindService(intent, MyService.serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    public static void unbind(final Context context) {
        context.unbindService(MyService.serviceConnection);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        // not being called
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        // not being called
    }

    private void bound() {}

    private void unbound() {
        // not being called
    }
}
```

Then in my activity I simply do this to bind:

```
MyService.bind(this);
```

and this to unbind:

```
MyService.unbind(this);
```

The problem is that it seems that I have no way of knowing when the user have swiped the activity off the recent.

Here's what I tried:

1. Use the activity `onDestroy` method: nope, not being called
2. Use the activity `onPause`/`onStop` methods: can't really distinguish between swipe case to just going to the background, as the `isFinishing()` results in `false` in all cases.
3. Use the service `onTaskRemoved` or `onUnbind` methods: not being called
4. In my `AndroidManifest.xml` adding `android:stopWithTask="true"` in the service element: that indeed kills my service when the activity is swiped, **but** it results in: `MyActivity has leaked ServiceConnection`. Not exactly sure why, but my guess is that I did not get the chance to call the `unbindService()`.

What am I doing wrong or what am I missing?
Thanks.

Comment: onTaskRemoved works for me. Maybe try to start service as well. I use both bind and start.

Comment: Have you tried to use the Activities' onTaskRemoved? For me, onTaskRemoved worked, but afair I use it on the Activity. There, you can then e.g. call a cleanup method of the Service and unbind/stop it in turn.

Comment: @mklimek I wish to only bind to the service and avoid starting it.
@Newtron there's no `onTaskRemoved` for activities, only services as far as I know (or was able to find), and that's pretty stupid.

Comment: @NitzanTomer sorry, of course you are right; I remembered this wrong. I have now had a look at one of my projects with a bound service, onTaskRemoved worked there as it should. I will post some snippets.

Comment: @Newtron the `onTaskRemoved` is called if I don't have `android:stopWithTask="true"`, but then again the `MyActivity has leaked ServiceConnection` exception is thrown,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already mentioned by mklimek, `onTaskRemoved()` is the way to go for this.

I use it in a project with a bound service that is started and bound by an Activity. Here are the respective parts (I'll add a bit of context to be safe):

**Activity** calls custom `startService()` and `bindService()` helper methods from `onCreate()`:

```
private void startService() {
    Intent myServiceIntent = new Intent(this, packageName.MyService.class);
    startService(myServiceIntent);
}

private void bindService() {
    mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
            mService = MyServiceListener.Stub.asInterface(iBinder);

            try {
                mService.registerCallback(myServiceCallback);
                mService.doSomething();
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                MLog.w(TAG, "Exception on callback registration; Service has probably crashed.");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
            mService = null;
        }
   };

    if(!myServiceIsBound) {
        Intent myServiceIntent = new Intent(this, packageName.MyService.class);
        bindService(myServiceIntent, mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        myServiceIsBound = true;
        // service is now bound
    } else {
        // service has already been bound
    }

}
```

Now, to the **Service** class: in it's `onCreate()`, I show a notification (which is afaik required for running background services) and set up the Binder:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Setup Binder for IPC
    mBinder = new MyServiceBinder();

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    [...display notification code...] 
}
```

Service interface (tell me if that's interesting, otherwise I just leave it out here):

```
private class MyServiceBinder extends MyServiceListener.Stub {

    @Override
    public void registerCallback(MyServiceCallback callback) throws RemoteException {
         [...]
    }

    // further methods for the service interface...
}
```

My `onTaskRemoved()` and the other lifecycle methods look as follows:

```
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);

    // do something adequate here
}


// Lifecycle management
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}


// Binding
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    return super.onUnbind(intent);
}
```

My `onTaskRemoved()` is called every time I swipe the Activity from the recent apps list. Are you sure your `onTaskRemoved()` method is not called (did you put some logging code there)? Also make sure to call the `super.onTaskRemoved()` method within it.

Our code looks quite similar, except that I put the ServiceConnection setup and Service binding code into the Activity. You moved a lot of this logic into the Service itself.

I can only guess that maybe here lies the problem with the leaking of the Service connection, as your ServiceConnection is a static member of your Service class, and you maintain a reference to your Service from within your ServiceConnection (via your "instance" variable). I'm not sure, but it seems both links are not broken, when the Activity is terminated. Mind, how in my code the ServiceConnection is a member of the Activity, and I clear the reference to `mService` in `onServiceDisconnected()` to be safe. Maybe you can refactor this a bit, taking references that cannot be GCed upon Activity termination into account.

Comment: but when swiped, don't you sometimes get `Activity has leaked ServiceConnection` exception?

Comment: No, I bet because my ServiceConnection dies with the destroyed Activity. There is no reference to the ServiceConnection from my Service; only the mServiceConnection variable within the Activity.
In your code, it is absolutely certain that the ServiceConnection lives beyond the Activity, as you made it static within the Service class. This also looks dangerous to me, because what happens if you let multiple Activities bind to your Service? All of them will bind using the same ServiceConnection, I'm pretty sure that this should not be done this way.

Comment: Try the following in your code: don't make the `ServiceConnection` static and let the Activity instantiate it.
This will also have you get rid of your `instance.bound()` and `instance.unbound()` methods in the Service. Because, if you create a Service connection from the Activity and bind the Activity to a Service, the `onBind()` and `onUnbind()` methods overriden from the Service superclass get called anyway, doing exactly what you intended with your own methods. Why not use them?

Comment: Well, I simplified the way I bind to the service and now indeed do it from my activity, but still I sometimes get that exception. It's not that much of a big deal as it happens only after the user have killed the activity using swipe, but it's annoying none the less...

Comment: Strange. Unfortunately, I don't know what else could be the problem. BTW, do you register callbacks or maintain references from the service to the Activity? This could also cause some trouble (Activity cannot be GC'ed then)...  make sure to employ a `WeakReference` for this.