# Xamarin handle app being killed by using service, but how to cleanup resources in the main application

Tags: android, service, terminate

I have an application that uses some hardware resources and if a user kills the app by going to the task manager and swiping up the app is killed without any events and the hardware resources are not cleaned up.

I have found that I should implement a service and handle the onTaskRemoved event within the service. [see SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35459194/gracefully-clean-up-bound-service-when-activity-is-getting-swiped-from-the-recen/35462358)

```
public override void OnTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent)
{
    // Do something here? but what?
}
```

My real question is how do I cleanup the resources in the main application being killed by this as all samples I have seen don't actually do anything except log the event?

Comment: Have you tried using the `onDestroy` portion of the `Android Lifecyle`, I've used it in a similar situation and it works fine.

Comment: I will do some tests on that and post back here the results. Thanks

Comment: I found that the Android lifecycle did work for me once, but I then could not reproduce it. I went with the service and I managed to get what I wanted done.

I just did not realize that I had access to all of our static instance data from the onTaskRemoved event.